# VBA SQL Server Select

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I was wondering if you could please check my code in VBA (Excel) to retrieve data from a SQL Server database, and insert it in the sheet.

It returns an error according the picture attached.

[image]

```
Sub ConnectionTest()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim constr As String
constr = "Provider=sqloledb;Data source=USO-YEGANEH\SQL2008;Initial Catalgo=USO_Final;User Id=sa;Password=123"

Dim conRS As ADODB.Recordset
Set conRS = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open constr


With conRS

.ActiveConnection = conn
.Open "Select * from LatLong_Amar"
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset conRS
.Close

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I usually get this error when the table does not exist in the selected database or if it needs to be named differently.

Comment: It exist! What do you mean to be named differently?

Comment: For example it happens that some database engines want the table references like this: [LatLong_Amar].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is the problem, it seems full path of the table, despite the fact that database is defined in the Connection String, should be entered. So, the line `"Select * from LatLong_Amar"` should be changed to `[USO_Final].[dbo].[Latlong_Amar]`

```
Sub ConnectionTest()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

Dim constr As String
constr = "Provider=sqloledb;Data source=USO-YEGANEH\SQL2008;Initial Catalgo=USO_Final;User Id=sa;Password=123"

Dim conRS As ADODB.Recordset
Set conRS = New ADODB.Recordset

conn.Open constr


With conRS

.ActiveConnection = conn
.Open "Select * from [USO_Final].[dbo].[Latlong_Amar]"
Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset conRS
.Close

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The database is not defined in the connection string - you have `Initial Catalgo` instead of `Initial Catalog`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Server_Name = "YOUR_SERVER_NAME" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "AdventureWorksLT2012" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]" ' Enter your SQL here

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:z500") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is another option for you to muse over.

```
Sub TestMacro()

' Create a connection object.
Dim cnPubs As ADODB.Connection
Set cnPubs = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

'Connect to the Pubs database on the local server.
strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=(local);INITIAL CATALOG=NORTHWIND.MDF;"

'Use an integrated login.
strConn = strConn & " INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"

'Now open the connection.
cnPubs.Open strConn

' Create a recordset object.
Dim rsPubs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsPubs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsPubs
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    ' Extract the required records.
    .Open "SELECT * FROM Categories"
    ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsPubs

    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With

cnPubs.Close
Set rsPubs = Nothing
Set cnPubs = Nothing

End Sub
```